# custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 XML files called spring-context.xml and spring-view.xml. spring-context.xml is declared inside the context context-param tag in web.xml file.

`spring-view.xml` file is declared inside the spring servlet init-param in web.xml. I have declared propertyConfigurer bean in `spring-context.xml`. The following code in spring-view.xml

```
    <bean name="/home" class="com.company.web.controller.view.HomeViewController" >
    <property name="msg" value="${message}"></property>
    </bean>
```

`${message}` not resolved .

If I declare the `propertyConfurer` bean in spring-view.xml `${message}` is resolved and working very fine.

What could be problem here.

If I declare a `propertyConfigurer` bean in spring-context.xml. This `propertyConfigurer` bean is accessible in spring-view.xml ?

Comment: Someone else [suggested it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3015563) Jack, I did more to the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No... Bean(Factory)PostProcessor operate only on/in the `ApplicationContext` they are loaded in. The Bean(Factory)PostProcessors in the root context don't operate/modify beans in the child contexts and vice-versa.

You need to declare the beans twice to have placeholders replaced in both contexts.